# Oracle Database remote access of sqlplus via linux

Tags: linux, database, oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have a Oracle Database installed on remote linux server (say 192.168.0.142 ) and I am able to connect via db client like sqldeveloper. However I have a use case where I want to access 'sqlplus' of remote DB Server from a local linux machine (say 192.168.0.2). Anyone have any idea about how to do this?

Possible Use case- I have to execute a script that contains $ORACLE_HOME path of remote server. When this script executes it looks for $ORACLE_HOME path and try to execute some stuff at remote DB server only. Currently I have tried below options already in local script (at 192.168.0.2)-

$ORACLE_HOME=oracle/oracle@192.168.0.142:1521/ux
[Where oracle/oracle => username/password of machine 192.168.0.142 and ux is SID]

$ORACLE_HOME=uxinsight/welcome1@192.168.0.142:1521/ux
[Where uxinsight/welcome1=> username/password of DB user 192.168.0.142 and ux is SID]

$ORACLE_HOME=uxinsight/welcome1@192.168.0.142:1521/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_home1
[Where uxinsight/welcome1=> username/password of DB user at 192.168.0.142]

$ORACLE_HOME=oracle/oracle@192.168.0.142:1521/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_home1
[Where oracle/oracle=> username/password of machine 192.168.0.142]

All tried settings throw a common error message: **sqlplus not found on location $ORACLE_HOME[the path set in above optios]**

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Two obvious options here (as far as I see) and depending on the use case: 1. Use of Database links, but this would require you to connect to sqlplus on the host machine and then within it, to execute smth like `select * from table_name@remote_database where ...`. 2. What about ssh to the remote host and starting a sqlplus connection there from this "tunnel". Which one of those covers your case or neither one ?

Comment: @g00dy Thanks for your quick response. Use case 1 is desired here. However the database links I have tried are not working. Do you have any reference where I can find the Database Link structure/example or please share if you have that. Thanks!